# Can I run WordPress directly from IntelliJ?

Tags: wordpress, intellij-idea

Currently I'm programming inside IntelliJ and running a Webserver via MAMP. Because I have a lot of problems with MAMP, I want to know, if it's possible to run WP via a run configuration right out of IntelliJ? How are you dealing with this?

Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/preparing-to-use-wordpress.html) might be what you're looking for.

*[Edit]*

However, I must ask, are you developing through community or ultimate? Wordpress framework support is available only on Ultimate, so that's one thing to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run WP using [Built-in Web Server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/php-built-in-web-server.html). But built-in web server provides much less flexibility then AMP packages so I would advise to stick to MAMP. If you have any particular issues with it - just contact IDEA support via Help | Contact Support.